# ArgoCD+Prometheus: Total amount of syncs

Tags: prometheus, grafana, argocd

I'm trying to setup a bar chart visualization for: **"How many syncs I have done per application for a specific time interval"** with the help of the metric: `argocd_app_sync_total`(https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/metrics/#application-controller-metrics)

I setup a prometheus PromQL query `sum by (name) (round(increase(argocd_app_sync_total [$__range]))) > 0`, but it doesn't give me the response I want, instead it counts some synced app which hasn't been synced.
Has anyone done something similar or can point me in a direction on how to do it? Am I misunderstanding how the counter works? Should it be something else than `$__range`?